# Backup keystore with Terminal?

Tags: wallets, backup

I am running ethereum wallet v0.7.4, once the block had updated it seems as though it has killed my wallet and it keeps crashing as soon as I open it. I see my keystore in terminal, I would like to move it.

I have tried cp /keystore/. /location which didn't work so I tried cp -r /keystore/. /location/ and still no luck.

I am on a mac....so I thought perhaps I could show hidden files and just copy them that way....are there any other ways?
Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Folder view going to Library and within it finding Ethereum folder? Finder -> Shift + Cmd + G will take you there straightaway and you can do a copy from there. Inside Ethereum folder you should get the keystore folder.

Additionally, cp is for copying a target file to a target directory. Keystore is a folder which is a directory rather than being a file. That's why it is not working. There are key files within the keystore folder.

Had related issue earlier. I simply copied my keystore folder somewhere else on my Mac. Check this out [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts) for importing private key from any other directory.

Comment: thanks for the response, yes however I couldn't see the folder/file so I gathered it might be a hidden, so I exposed hidden files. Intially I downloaded the ethereum wallet executed it and I happened to be running it from "my downloads". ....which is bad I am sure and now I am paying the price. So I used -r to copy the directory which gave me no love. When I used the ls command on the keystore folder I can see my various keys......most annoying! I just can't seem to get them to do a complete reinstall of the wallet and import them.

Comment: If you have your keys backed up, why can't you simple delete all folders related to Ethereum? 

Have edited my answer for a way to do that. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks mate I will give it a go and let you know how it goes....